# Add two large numbers as strings

Tags: arrays, c, type-conversion, char, ansi-c

I'm not adding "real" code here code snippets, because I've tried so many variations - with varying success - that I'm just going to use C-like pseudo code.

===

I want to add two numbers that exceed `ANSI C`'s largest `long long` (such as two 50 digit numbers)

The idea is that I would use two `char[]` arrays and do a classic pen-and-paper style addition by converting each character of the two addends to ints, adding and carrying the tens, and then assigning the results as a `char` again to a `char[]` array.

The problems I'm running into is converting the `char` to `int` (which always fails) ... and then adding the result to a another text array. Trying to add a character to the `char result[]`using `result[i] = "5"` or even its ascii value `result[i] = 53` always fails.

**pseudo code**

```
int add(char *n1, char *n2){
    // examples (Intentionally not the same length)
    // n1     = "12345678901234567890"
    // n2     =      "987654321098765"
    char result[100]; // array for resulting added ints as char
    int r = 100; // The index (set to end) for the result array 
    result[r] = 0; // Assign the char-halt to END of the result
    int carry = 0; //  for carrying the 10s
    maxlength = <length of largest addend> // (sizeof(n)/sizeof(n[0])) doesnt work because pointers

    // start at end (right end) of arrays and move towards start (left end)
    // each loop takes one character, starting at the far RIGHT (end) of the string array
    // i = (maxlength - 1) to skip stop "0"
    for (int i = (maxlength - 1); i >= 0; i--) { 
        a1 = int()n1[i] // doesnt return correct value in tests. Neither does a1 = n1[i]-0
        a2 = int()n1[i] // doesnt return correct value in tests. Neither does a1 = n1[i]-0
        int asum = a1 + a2 + carry

        // carry all the tens
        carry = 0; // reset carry
        while (asum > 10){
            carry += 10; 
            asum -= 10; 
        }
        result[r] = char()asum 
        r -= 1 // Move result index one to the LEFT
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no known character encoding where e.g. `'1' == 1`. The most common character encoding is [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), and if you look at the digits I'm sure you could find some pattern and an easy way to convert the encoded digit to its integer equivalent (hint: it involves subtraction between ***characters***).

Comment: Also, when creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), even if it's pseudo-code, then make sure it doesn't contain such obvious errors are your failed casts.

Comment: Try `char c = '7'; int i =  c - '0'; printf("c = %c, i = %d\n", c, i);`

Comment: @alk HA! That actually solved BOTH the problems of converting it to an int, AND adding it to the result array.  The issue was I didn't put single quotes around the zero in the equation. If you want to rephrase this as an answer, I'll select it and upvote. Thx!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I appreciate the direction. Those casts, which did fail, were from answers for solving similar problems about ansi c on StackOverflow. I'm new to c, so I didn't realize they were obvious errors. Are those not valid casts in ansi c?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *The problems I'm running into is converting the `char` to `int` ...*

The C Standard guarantees that the 10 characters `'0'` to `'9'` hold consecutively and increasing values:

> [5.2.1 Character sets](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1)
>
> [...]
>
> [3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1p3) Both the basic source and basic execution character sets shall have the following members:
>   the 10 decimal digits
>
> 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
>
> [...] the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

Look at this and get the concept:

```
#include stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char c = '7'; 
  int i = c - '0'; 

  printf("c = %c, i = %d\n", c, i); 
}
```

Comment: I don't think C in `ASCII` is what guarantees that "in C" (give me one programming language which has something different than ASCII for basic characters, sigh), '0' to '9' will be consecutive `char` values in range `[48; 57]` but other than that this is a good answer. ASCII also has nothing to do with C standard. `printf()` and similar might be in C's standard, but what gets printed on screen really isn't up to C standard to define as `printf()` in a nutshell is just a syscall to OS with arbitrary bytes that will be printed however OS pleases.

Comment: @PurpleIce my answer does not talk about ASCII in any way.

Comment: @PurpleIce ... more over C does not know ASCII. Only its Implementation knows ... and are some, to not say many.

Comment: @Purpleice: For example read the 3rd sentence [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSB23S_1.1.0.14/gtpa2/char51.html). And there are C compilers for the "boxes" sold by this company... ;-)

Comment: My point is that charcodes from '0' to '9' aren't part of C standard, it's ASCII standard that's used globally. If you want to argue about that, then might aswell say that every OS that can run machine code emitted by C compilers are part of C standard. Because you know, in fact, C relies on particular environment and it could run in environment where charcodes are completely different for every letter and it would still run correctly, it has nothing to do with C itself, for the program itself, it's just arbitrary numbers and OS handles them when you print it out on screen :)

Comment: Therefore, saying "C Standard" guarantees is completely wrong. Anyone could write an OS in an evening where it wouldn't be like that yet programs emitted by gcc would still run properly, and then it would break the standard, because standard doesn't guarantee it. OS's that use charcodes that are globally the same, because we like when things are the same everywhere, do.

Comment: @PurpleIce my answer quotes the C Standard, even links to a copy of it. So please have a 2nd Look and then tell me which part of the answer you feel is wrong.

Comment: @PurpleIce Sure, my answer is written from the perspective of a C programmer. The question is tagged C.

Comment: This is """guaranteed""" only if you compile your program to most popular platforms, that is, Unix based systems, Windows, macOS, modifications of them like Android etc. Like I said, if a new system arose, it would pretty much invalidate that. That part is written with asumption that such thing will never happen, it, on it's own, does not guarantee that. Instead of pretending that it does guarantee it, you should know on which platforms that will be true. Remember that this answer might be read 10 years later where, for example, Windows, might even be obsolete.

Comment: ...where main character set would have numbers like `0`, `2`, `4`, `6`, `8`, `1`, `3`, `5`, `7`, `9`. Because, who knows? That's still better than dealing with winAPI. But you know, I don't think C will be obsolete 10 years later. And what will happen with this "guarantee" which was never guaranteed, just heavily assumed? Character sets are it's own thing and don't depend on language AT ALL. They aren't even interacted with directly by C program, OS takes your charcodes and converts them to glyphs when it renders them on screen, how could C standard even affect that whatsoever?